# Facebook SDK PHP Display a users email address

Tags: php, facebook, api, email, sdk

So I am using the Facebook SDK for Facebook Login and have followed their docs as it shows although I can't seem to figure out how to echo the users email address?

I can see it does pick up email although the email address does not display in METADATA:

```
object(Facebook\Authentication\AccessTokenMetadata)#17 (1) { ["metadata":protected]=> array(7) { ["app_id"]=> string(15) "1234565678" ["application"]=> string(4) "PLFT" ["expires_at"]=> object(DateTime)#21 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-06-11 10:47:32.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } ["is_valid"]=> bool(true) ["issued_at"]=> object(DateTime)#22 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-04-12 10:47:32.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } ["scopes"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "email" [1]=> string(14) "public_profile" } ["user_id"]=> string(16) "36346346346346" } }
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
<?
session_start();
include 'system/db.php';
require_once 'fb_connect/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '346364326346346',
  'app_secret' => 'reyeryeryeryeerwyer346436',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);
// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('43141346436316'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
print_r($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);


// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');

?>
```

Any idea as to how I can display user data around the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you got access token you can pass it to graph API to get user details by passing token.

```
      <?php

      $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
          'app_id' => '',
          'app_secret' => '',
          'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
      ]);

      try {
          // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
          // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
          $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,email,location,gender,birthday,hometown', $access_token);
      } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
      } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo $e->getMessage();
      }

      // Get user details from facebook.
      $me = $response->getGraphUser();

     print_r($me);
```

?>

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, although with this I seem to only get the Name, Gender and ID of user even though I have requested access to Email. 

Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [name] => Aidan Thompson [gender] => male [id] => 17346346346346 ) )

Comment: You can check your app has permission to access email. To check this visit you FB app and Click on "App Review" and see "Approved Item section"

Comment: It does seem to have permission and is approved by default so I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Make your app public by clicking "Make ... public?" button.

Comment: If still you are not get then you need to "Submit Items for Approval".